# Javascript - biggest number from array using loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, max

Can somebody please explain how this code gets which number from array is the biggest?

```
var num = [];
for( var i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
     num[i] = parseInt( prompt("Unesite broj " + (i+1) + "." ) );
}

var biggest = 0;
for(i=0; i < num.length; i++ ) {
    if( num[i] > biggest ) {
        biggest = num[i];   
    }
}

console.log("The biggest number is " + biggest );
```

Comment: What exactly don't you understand about the code? It's quite straightforward.

Comment: It loops through the array and stores the biggest. Nothing more to say about that. What part exactly has you dumbfounded?

Comment: .. It contains a bug, though: it fails totally when you enter only negative numbers.

Comment: FYI the following code does the same thing: `Math.max.apply(null, num)`.

Comment: @Andy: Except that returns doesn't return `0` with no or negative `num`s, as Jongware complained

Comment: Why would it return zero on an empty array? That doesn't make any sense. At least this version returns the proper value if you load the array with negative values, even if there's a zero in there somewhere.

Comment: The array cannot be empty. (But it can contain all `NaN`s, per [`parseInt` rules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt). I wonder if those are bigger or smaller than `0`...)

Comment: @Jongware Neither larger nor smaller, and not equal (or equivalent) either. NaNs should be discarded by this algorithm.

Comment: @ssube: I guessed so much. The suggested improvenet elsewhere, using `num[0]` as starting point, could fail as well if the first number is not-a-number. Also, what should be returned if the entire array is invalid? (I think I'd go for `undefined` rather than `NaN`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start, we've seen no numbers, and the code assumest the biggest is 0 or larger:

```
var biggest = 0;
```

We'll look at each number in the list:

```
for(i=0; i < num.length; i++ ) {
```

Is the current number bigger than the biggest we've seen?

```
  if( num[i] > biggest ) {
```

If so, it's the *new* biggest number

```
    biggest = num[i];   
  }
}
```

When the loop is done, `biggest` contains the largest number we saw along the way.

Comment: "To start, we've seen no numbers" -- then how can you assume the rest is all larger than your arbitrary 'largest *possible*' value?

Comment: @Jongware It's not my code. OP asked for an explanation. Are you seriously downvoting the answer because you don't like the initial conditions of the code in the question?

Comment: (Note: It's a failure in the OP's code. However, we don't know the input values and so you cannot discount this as a possible cause for the confusion on such a simple routine.)

Comment: (Made a minor edit in the first line just to point out the assumption and be able to retract -1. As an explanation of the code, this indeed is sound.)

Answer (score 0):

The if statement within the loop checks whether the number in the current element of the array is greater than the largest number found so far. If the current number is the greatest, the largest number found so far is updated to this new number.

Answer (score 0):

First `for` loop just prompts you to add numbers to an array.

The second loop just checks each number in the `num` array, if that number is bigger than the number in the `biggest` variable then it sets the `biggest` variable to that number.

It's as simple as that.

Comment: thanks for a very nice explanation. just one more question. what does num[ i ] means? is that just using each number from array?

Comment: @ringop That is one of the basics of javascript, if you dont know what that is you should really check out [JavaScript Basics](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/JavaScript_basics) and [JavaScript Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) and [For loop - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)